# Laravel Blade checkbox not checked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm passing variables into the blade from controller. This is my code from controller:

```
$offerConditionsData = Offercondition::where('offerId', $id)->where('deleted', '0')->get();
return view('Administrator.offers.add', $data);
```

I'm defining a variable at the top of the blade file:

```
@if(isset($offerConditionsData))
@foreach ($offerConditionsData as $offerConditions)
@php $selectedCondCheckbox = $offerConditions->keyword;
@endphp
@endforeach
@endif
```

If I echo the $selectedCondCheckbox, then I found the below:

> customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories

Now I want that if the variable value matched with a constant, the correct checkbox will checked. Below are the code in the blade file to check the checkbox from a bunch of check boxes.

```
<input type="radio" name="condition_tab" value="1" class="flat-red" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" @php if(isset($selectedCondCheckbox) == 'customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories') { echo "checked=checked"; } else { echo ""; } @endphp>

<input type="radio" name="condition_tab" value="2" class="flat-red" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" @php if(isset($selectedCondCheckbox) == 'discount_on_total_amount_of_shipping') { echo "checked=checked"; } else { echo ""; } @endphp>
```

However, I saw that second checkbox is checked. It should checked the first checkbox as the value of the php variable ,matched with the constant.

Comment: `isset($selectedCondCheckbox) == 'customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories'`
I think `isset()` returns boolean and it never can be a string `customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories`

Comment: So what will be the solution? I'm using Add and Edit in the same form and thus I'm using isset so that it will not effect during adding.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="condition_tab" value="1" class="flat-red" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" {{ isset($selectedCondCheckbox) ?  $selectedCondCheckbox == 'customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories' ? 'checked=checked' :'' :'' }} >` hope this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is certainly some mistake with your if condition

try the conditions separately

```
       @php if(isset($selectedCondCheckbox)) { 
            if($selectedCondCheckbox =='discount_on_total_amount_of_shipping') 
            { echo "checked=checked"; }}@endphp
```

Answer (score 3):

try it with this Code

```
<input type="radio" name="condition_tab" value="1" class="flat-red" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" {{ isset($selectedCondCheckbox) ? $selectedCondCheckbox == 'customer_get_discounts_and_special_offers_on_certain_product_or_categories' ? 'checked=checked' :'' :'' }} >

<input type="radio" name="condition_tab" value="2" class="flat-red" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" {{ isset($selectedCondCheckbox) ? $selectedCondCheckbox == 'discount_on_total_amount_of_shipping' ? 'checked=checked' :'' :'' }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently laravel added [@checked](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#checked-and-selected) function

```
<input type="checkbox"
        name="active"
        value="active"
        @checked(old('active', $user->active)) />
```